# Generating means from bivariate gaussian distribution

Tags: statistics, data-science, gaussian-process, gaussian-mixture-model

I am reading the book "The elements of statistical learning" Ch 2 and on page 16 there is this line - 'First we generate 10 means m_k from a bivariate gaussian distribution N((1,0),I) and labelled BLUE. Similarly, 10 more were drawn from N((0,1),I) and labelled ORANGE. Then for each class we generate 100 observations,...'

I m unable to understand this paragraph. I have following questions:
Q1 What does generating 10 means from a bivariate gaussian distribution implies ? How can we generate mean ? If there is any mathematical formula please do tell.

Q2 Difference between N((1,0),I) and N((0,1),I) ?
Does 1st implies mean = 1 and variance = 0 and second one's vice-versa ?

I don't know about clustering yet since I thought I was going through supervised learning and clustering comes under the category of unsupervised learning. Should I learn about clustering first to understand this paragraph ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have said, you have two distributions: first is `N((1,0),I)` (BLUE points) and second is `N((0,1),I)` (ORANGE points) where

```
I = [[1, 0],
     [0, 1]]
```

the identity matrix. The bivariate normal distribution has a pdf that you can draw from using any rudimentary technique such as the `MASS` package's `rmvrnorm` or MCMC techniques. Since you have 10 from the first and 10 from the second if you plot the points on a 2-D graph you'll have the blue points centered around `(1,0)` in a circle and the orange points around `(0,1)`. Then it sounds like you have a classification task which is indeed unsupervised learning.